# is it possible to send UDP broadcasts over wifi without being connected to a network?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, wifi, broadcast

I am trying to get the time of flight for a packet between 2 Raspberry pis that are set up as access points.

Right now I can transmit a broadcast between them as long as they are connected to the same network.

My thought was that I could send out UDP broadcasts without them being connected to a network, similar to how beacon packets and probe requests are sent.

this is my server code, I am using wireshark to receive packets on the otherside.

```
import sys, time
import socket, IN

port = 22222
interface = "wlan0"
broadcast = "255.255.255.255"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, IN.SO_BINDTODEVICE, interface + "\0")

while 1:
    s.sendto("test data", (broadcast, port))
    time.sleep(2)
```

does anybody know if this is possible? a point in the right direction would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to send/received UDP/IP packets when the device is not connected to network. IP layer requires the link layer is connected.

Beacon packets and probe request does not require connected network but they are not IP packets (they have no IP header at all) so it is not possible to construct and send them via AF_INET sockets. Raw packets on wifi can be created and sent via the raw socket. But if you tried to construct a packet with IP and UDP header manually and send it to network nobody would respond it because the sender is not connected to the network.

The python library https://github.com/kbandla/python-wifitools supports the constructing raw 802.11 messages like beacon packet but you will never send a valid UDP/IP packet if the node is not connected.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this information.. This is what I've been looking for!